# Typescript discriminated union with boolean and IFs only work with an explicit check

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I've seem to have hit some sort of weird edge case in Typescript. Here's the code:

```
type T = {
    a: false,
    b: number;
} | {
    a: true;
    c: number;
};

let y: T = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: false, b: 1 } : { a: true, c: 2 };

if (y.a) {
    console.log(y.c);
} else {
    console.log(y.b); // <--- Error here. Can use neither `b` nor `c`
}
```

As written, this code does not compile. In the `else` branch Typescript seems to thing that `y.a` is an undetermined `boolean`, rather than `false`. Hence also neither `y.b` nor `y.c` are accessible.

If I change that to an explicit check:

```
if (y.a == true) {
```

Then all works. Except that it looks weird (why do you need to compare to `true`?)

Am I missing something here or is this a bug in Typescript?

Comment: My guess for the reason for the explicit check is that in the boolean context of the if statement the type of `y.a` is `boolean` but the explicit comparison allows the compiler to narrow it from `boolean` to the literal type `true`.

Comment: That code doesn't compile for me simply because you're using `y` before it's assigned.  If I `declare` it or initialize it then I don't see the issue you're mentioning.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WoM0gN).  So either I can't reproduce your issue or the problem is that you have unresolved errors before the issue you mention.  Which is it?

Comment: @jcalz OK, I omitted assigning the variable to make the example simpler. I fixed it now.

Comment: Works for me still: https://tsplay.dev/mpQE7W

Comment: @kelsny - Ahh, interesting. Disabling `strictNullChecks` creates the error. That makes more sense - I believe it assumes that `y.a` can also be `null`.